# Vertically center h2 and sub-heading

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a website and wanted to see how I could vertically center h2 and the sub-heading with respect to the div that contains the image.

Basically, I have a container with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`. I have three columns.

The first column contains a profile image along with a header and sub-header. What's the best way to vertically center the `.title` div?

Here's a link to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzj4omo8/2/)

Comment: Per [**SO guidelines**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you need to post your code in the question itself. Otherwise, if your external demo ever fails, the post becomes much less useful.

Comment: Oh ok, I wasn't aware of this. I will update my question. Thank you for that recommendation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give `display: flex` to class `profile-container`, then you can align it's child profile image and title class to vertically center like below:

```
.profile-container{
 display : flex;
 align-items : center;
 height : 200px; //provide wrapper height
}
```

This should achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute positioned, with a -50% transform.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background: white;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .09);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/*set up vertical column layouts for the three containers*/

.profile-container,
.work-container,
.social-media-container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.profile-container {
  align-self: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.profile-image {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://organicthemes.com/demo/profile/files/2012/12/profile_img.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.header-name {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
      <div class="container">

        <div class="profile-container">
          <div class="profile-image"></div>
          <div class="title">
            <h2>Tarang Hirani</h2>
            <h6>Software Engineer</h6>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="work-container">
          These are my projects
        </div>

        <div class="social-media-container">
          Social media link
        </div>
      </div>
```

Link for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/kzj4omo8/3/

Comment: This seems like it works! Is this the best way to do it? I'm trying to have the cleanest possible solution. Also, is the `display: inline-block` the correct way  to get those `divs` aligned?

Comment: It is a clean and correct way to align it vertically. You could use flex, but if you're trying to make this cross-browser compatible with older versions of IE, flex might not be supported.