# Can't center h2 in div via bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Morning friends! What am i doing wrong?

```
<div class="col-4" style="">
    <h2 class="text-center vertical-center">Text here</h2>
</div>
```

Tried several classes but no profit

Comment: Found the solution. thx to this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962388/21159498)

Comment: Consider answering your question to describe the "solution" to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 is already in center mode but the thing is that your col-4 so you can't see this. you should do col-12 than you see the h2 is actual in center.